# passing arguments into a python script from cmd line or a bash script

Tags: python, bash, variables, arguments

simple question.

If I have this line:

```
      j = json.load(urllib.urlopen("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q= ***$???*** "))
```

I'm trying to pass an argument into that spot from another script +/or the command line.

In bash its simple, $1, $2, etc etc.

I've read about (sys.argv[1]) and I'm missing it because such a simple thing in bash seems to need such verbose-ness in python. I've tried this:

```
      j = json.load(urllib.urlopen("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q='(sys.argv[1])'"))
```

To no avail....
What am I not understanding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings are not interpolated by default in Python. Try

```
("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q='%s'"
 % sys.argv[1])
```

Comment: if i had not asked on here... how would i have come upon that tidbit?
what's the understand behind that...it worked btw, i'll check it once time is cleared.

Comment: @sirvonandrethomas: the fact that some other languages magically interpolate strings doesn't mean Python should do that. I think `%` is actually in the tutorial.

Comment: @sirvonandrethomas - http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/interpreter.html#argument-passing and http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#old-string-formatting

Answer (score 0):

Yep, for completeness, there's "new formatting" which is a bit like Java's format strings, and a little nicer to work with.

```
 $ python -c 'import sys; print("yojo{0}".format(sys.argv[1]))' mo
yojomo
```

And if you just want to concatenate strings, the `+` operator is overloaded for that.

```
print("mystring" + sys.argv[1])
```